# Aptana; What does the ">" in front of file/folder names mean in the File explorer?

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana

I'w wondering what it means when Aptana IDE displays an > in the beginning of file and folder names in the File explorer?

Comment: Dunno, perhaps ask Aptana's documentation?

Comment: i think, it mean that the file has been change.

Comment: @delnan Been there, done that, googled it. But no wiser.

@singularity But it's still there even after saving changes to the file. Also i notice it's just in my Aptana and not in my Eclipse.

Comment: I recently installed the EGit addon in Aptana, could that be the cause? But i can't remember if the arrow was there before EGit was installed o not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '>' character could mean incoming or outgoing changes (not sure about the direction) to version control systems.

Otherwise look for decorators in preferences (possibly label decorators, but not sure).

Comment: You're right. I found it now in Preferences > Team > Git > Label Decorations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, this indicates an outgoing uncommitted change in CVS.  Since Aptana is Eclipse based, I assume its the same thing.

You can change the decorator to something else (e.g. I have mine change the text to a different color) but that's the default.

See Window -> Preferences -> Team -> CVS -> Label Decorations, "Text Decorations" tab.

Comment: I think it might be the EGit addon doing it then, since i have not installed CVS on Aptana. Thanks!